# Blender bpy render giving incorrect image

Tags: python, rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have bpy setup as a python dependency and I use the following code to render:

```
self.bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_EEVEE'
self.bpy.context.scene.eevee.taa_render_samples = 1
self.bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
self.bpy_context.scene.render.filepath = "res.png"
self.bpy_ops.render.render(write_still=True)
self.__export_blender_scene("/projectX/tmp/blender.blend")
```

The resulting image I am getting from this code is incorrect.

I do get the correct image if I open up the saved blend file and click on render without changing anything, or if I run the following command from cmd:

```
blender -b blender.blend -o //render_##### -f -2
```

or if I simply change the render engine from 'BLENDER_EEVEE' to 'CYCLES' in my python code.

Is this a bug in 3.6 for python support? Thanks

Comment: And what do you mean by 'incorrect' image? No image? Completely black? Incorrect colors?

Comment: @SietseBrouwer it does generate an image with correct dimensions, but the image looks like it is extremely zoomed in on 1 or 2 pixels.